# Equivalence class of $T$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y) T (a,b)$ iff $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

What is the equivalence class of $T$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y) T (a,b)$ iff $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$

I can see that the equivalence class cannot be negative, as the square of any real number is positive.

So is the equivalence class simply $\left \{ \mathbb{\left \{R  \right \}}> 0 \right \}$?

But I think this is incorrect since the equivalence class entails nothing (except the answer is always positive) about the relation T. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Two points are equivalent if they both lie on the same circle centred at the origin.

Comment: The class?? Rather the classes how you now that there is only one?

Comment: The equivalence class of $(x,y)$ under $T$. Instead the equivalence class of $T$. I agree with the M.B. comment. $T$ is the relation that assign a point lying in a circle centered at origin, with a point lying in the same circle.

Comment: "I can see that the equivalence class cannot be negative",What do you mean by negative? the equivalence class is a set. Perhaps it would be good to read the section on equivalence class again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalence classES of $T$ consists of all circles that are centered at the origin. $(x, y)T (a, b)$ then means that $(x, y)$ lies on the same circle as $(a, b)$, as do all points lying on that given circle of radius $r$. For each $r\in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, there is one and only one equivalence class, that being the set of points that lie on the circle $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

Comment: You have been busy again today! +1